# Can Parent Class call Dynamically created child class method in java?

Tags: java, loops, parent-child

I want to call method of dynamically  created child method from parent and than pass values to that class.

This is possible in java?

```
Class Parent {
    Child(1, 2, ..., N).someMethod();
}

//Dynamically created at any time and also deleted 
Class Child1 { }
Class Child2 { }
.
.
.
Class ChildN { }
```

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking. Please add some more code or more details about your desire.

Answer (score 0):

sure

```
Class Parent{
  Child child;

 // setup child somehow

  public void callChildMethod(){
      child.callMethod();
  }
}
```

just make sure child is overriding the method callMethod();

ps: you better present some example you need on domain you understand. Second: this is not java question